# Matcher and Regex in Java to output what's inside Square Brackets but only once

Tags: java, regex, grammar

I am having major trouble with understanding what is going wrong with a regex. To be complete I will lay out some background info.

This program is supposed to implement a SIMPLESEM interpreter. The grammar in concern here is this:

```
< Expr >    ==>   < Term > {( + | - ) < Term >}

< Term >    ==>   < Factor > {( * | / | % ) < Factor >}

< Factor >  ==>   < Number > | D[< Expr >] | (< Expr >)

< Number >  ==>   0 | (1..9){0..9}
```

I was provided with this code which is supposed to give me the contents inside the square brackets of a `< Factor >`, but it didn't work:

```
 Matcher m;

(m = Pattern.compile("D\\[(.*)").matcher(expr)).find();
        expr = parseExpr(m.group(1));
        (m = Pattern.compile("\\](.*)").matcher(expr)).find();
        expr = m.group(1);
```

As example input i have this:

```
jumpt 5, D[0] == 0
```

The `< Factor >` concerned here is `D[0]`. It doesn't work because the function above feeds `0]` into `parseExpr()` which doesn't handle the left over bracket, and it shouldn't. So i switched it to:

```
(m = Pattern.compile("D\\[(.*)").matcher(expr)).find();
        expr = m.group(1);
        (m = Pattern.compile("\\](.*)").matcher(expr)).find();
        expr = parseExpr(m.group(1));
```

but this didn't work because of the Matcher/Regex.
I believe it outputted an empty string.
So then I tried this which just gives me an error that there is no match:

```
(m = Pattern.compile("D\\[(.*)").matcher(expr)).find();
expr = m.group(1);

if(expr.contains("(.*)")) 
{
    (m = Pattern.compile("\\](.*)").matcher(expr)).find();
}
else
{
    (m = Pattern.compile("\\]").matcher(expr)).find();
}   
    expr = m.group(1);
    expr = parseExpr(expr);
```

It gives an index out of bounds at the second to last line.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this part `D[ <Expr> ]` and `( <Expr> )`, which introduces the problem of bracket matching. This is not something Java regex can handle, since it doesn't support recursive regex.

In this case, regex is only useful for lexing, you need to write a custom parser for your language.

Comment: This is the custom parser. I just don't understand why the Matcher/regex can parse "D[" out of "D[0]" but not "]". The matcher doesn't find the ] for some reason. I don't understand regex.

Comment: @user1831680: You are not doing it in the right way. Looking at your code, you are trying to consume whatever `.*` for the Expr inside `D[`, so it won't work correctly.

Comment: i thought that was outside of the D[0], as in parenthesis like D[0](1*2) or something. But even if what you are saying is true, the if statement at the end sends D[0] to the else statement where the pattern is just "\\\]" without the ".*" It gives an index out of bounds exception.

Comment: @user1831680: It gives index out of bounds, since you are accessing group 1, while there is no group in the regex.

Comment: and how is that added? I dont understand because it works on "D\["

Comment: @user1831680: Your code doesn't make any sense to me. I suggest that you read a proper guide to parsing before proceed any further.

Comment: actually, this worked. m being the Matcher type
m = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\]").matcher(expr)).find();

i'll give you the Check, because you helped me the most.

Comment: @user1831680: You don't need to accept answer if it doesn't help you with what you are doing. I'm just saying that what you are doing right now is not going to work in general case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data inside of the square brackets then your regex should look something like:

```
D\[([^\]]*)
```

which basically says "Take 'D[', then take everything from there on that isn't a ']' and store it in the match".

Check out [Regexper](http://www.regexper.com/) to obtain a visualization of your regular expressions.

Comment: It is very easy to fail your regex, since the grammar is there. How are you going to deal with `D[D[0] + D[7 + D[4 + (5 + 6)]] + (6 + (8 + (5)) + D[3])]`?

Comment: True, didn't see that.  Well in that case, use ANTLR